# Gradle Dependencies aren't included in jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm very new to Gradle and the main reason I use it because I need to resolve dependencies issues for my compiled jar.

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '0.9'

jar {
    manifest {
      attributes 'Main-Class': 'wd.nlp.FileImport', 'Implementation-Title': 'WD\
NLP', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir(dirs: 'lib')
}

dependencies{
    compile 'mallet:mallet:2.0.7'
}
```

My Java files all depend on a third-party library called `Mallet`. Here is my folder structure:

```
 |---1.10
 |-----taskArtifacts
 |-build
 |---classes
 |-----main
 |-------wd
 |---------nlp
 |---dependency-cache
 |---libs
 |---tmp
 |-----jar
 |-lib
 |-src
 |---main
 |-----java
 |-------wd
 |---------nlp
 |-----resources
```

I placed `Mallet-2.0.7.jar` inside `lib` under the top folder. Then I used `gradle build` command and try to run my class:

`java -classpath build/libs/JavaClassifier-0.9.jar wd.nlp.FileImport -train ...`

Then I am told:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cc/mallet/pipe/Pipe
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
```

The `Mallet` library's path is `cc.mallet.*`...and now I don't know what to do...please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency is not include because you don't create a distribution of you project. In Maven it is called an assembly.

If you call your application directly from the commandline it is not a matter of Gradle.

Anyway there is a Gradle plugin which creates a distribution and adds shell scripts to execute your application.

So when you add the following line to the gradle script.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

you will get some new tasks to create a distribution.

Comment: Thank you! It did take me to the next step...and I was able to `run` it through Gradle. Well, then this happened: `Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1` Is this about my program? My Java path is correct. I run the line above on my console, and it is the location of `java` command.

Comment: If I forgot to mention...my program main class does take in some command line arguments.

Comment: You can add arguments by adding `run { args 'your', 'arguments' }` to your build.gradle

Comment: I guess the exit value comes from the missing argument. But I'm not sure since I don't know how your source code looks like. Did you try to pass arguments? The shell scripts will forward those to the main class.

Comment: I have various `System.exit(0);` to manage the passed in argument, certainly not `1`. Also I actually don't know how to pass arguments through command line when I'm running through Gradle.

Comment: @Aurel Thank you for that suggestion, but is there anyway to add it somewhere else than the `build.gradle`? It seems not very agile...if I have to open a text editor and change my arguments every time

Comment: @WindDweller This page explain how to easily pass arguments to `gradle run` : http://simonharrer.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/building-command-line-apps-with-gradle/

Comment: Sorry, I think was not clear enough. You can pass arguments to the generated shell scripts in the 'bin' folder of the distribution: build/install/<PROJECT_NAME/bin